# CGPathRelease necessary with Automatic Reference Counting?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

Is CGPathRelease necessary to use with CGPathCreate... functions with Automatic Reference Counting? I used Analyze but it shows no difference either way.

Comment: Maybe because they're not strictly Objective-C objects (under the hoods, we know they are), so maybe Apple was smart enough to turn these function calls into a no-operation when ARC is enabled.

Comment: You should release it with CFRelease. See [this answer][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569460/retaining-arc-objects-in-c-classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, CF functions aren't managed by ARC yet. Because you're calling `create`, I'd suggest putting in an appropriate release as well. Hopefully in the future everything (including CF calls) will be managed by ARC.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Would you mind providing a reference where you got that information for further reading? :)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII ..they certainly are when writing in Swift.

Comment: @ATV to be fair, at the time I wrote that comment (5 years ago), swift wasn't even a twinkle in Chris Lattner's eyes.